# jQuery DataTable display entries doesn't work

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

When I use the DataTables plugin, the show entries doesn't seem to work;
it only shows "show entries" but no dropdown.

```
<!-- datatable-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#statisticforteacher').DataTable({
               "paging":   true,
               "ordering": true,
               "info":     true,
               "pagingType": "full_numbers",
               "bLengthChange": true,
               "iDisplayLength" : 10,
               //"scrollY":        "200px",
               //"scrollCollapse": true,
               // "paging":         false
               select: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

As you can see, it shows entries without a dropdown and the search frame is so big. Where can I fix it and make it suitable?

[image]

**Blade**

```
<table id="statisticforteacher" class="table-responsive" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>FrageBezeichnung</th>
    <th>Kapitel</th>
    <th>richtige Antwort</th>
    <th>falsche Antwort</th>
    <th>Richtige Rate</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($data as $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$value -> Id}}</td>
        <td>{{$value -> FrageBezeichnung}}</td>
        <td>{{$value -> Kapitel}}</td>
        <td>{{$value -> richtigeAntwort}}</td>
        <td>{{$value -> falscheAntwort}}</td>
        <td>{{$value -> richtigeRate}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What have you tried to resolve that problem? And how is this related to Laravel, while you haven't shown any code related to that?

Comment: I have show it in picture, I use datatables plugin in my laravel project, I think the code I show is the key, so the Problem must be here. And when show entries works, it must have a dropdown, but it didn't. so that is doesn't work what I mean

Comment: Please add all clarification in text form. The image shows only two words without any context

Comment: yes, sure, as u can see the table right now

Comment: The space between around the -> operator is not a valid syntax. <td>{{$value -> Id}}</td> should be <td>{{$value->Id}}</td>